# Implement Salesforce Content Search in Salesforce Sites

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites

Within Salesforce on the Content Tab there is a search function that allows you to search within documents rather than just on titles. After much googling I haven't been able to find an example of how to add this to a visualforce page using Salesforce Sites. Does anyone have an e.g.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working using SOSL on the ContentVersion object